# cant draw images to canvas in js

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

Ok, so me and my friends are trying to make a game with html and js. I'm the one that has to build the foundation for the program to display the blocks used on the map. For some reason though, it doesn't want to draw my images on the canvas at all. I need to display a 24x32 array of 32x32 pixel blocks whose images I need to be able to change. I've looked online, and everywhere it says to use the function drawImage() but my program doesn't see that that belongs to the canvas under the 2d context. Here is my code:

index.html:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="canvas">
            <canvas id="canvas" height="768" width="1024" style="border:1px solid black">
                Your browser does not support canvas element.
            </canvas>

            <script type="text/javascript" src="Main.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="World Loader.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Main.js:

```
var c = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = "20px Arial";
var FPS = 60;
var Mode = 0;

function displayTick(){
    Map.DisplayChunk(0,0);
}

function gameTick(){

}

Chunk.LoadNew();
window.setInterval(displayTick, 1000 / FPS);
window.setInterval(gameTick, 600);
```

and World_Loader.js:

```
var Block={
    WalkThrough:true,
    SeeThrough:true,
    Interactable:false,
    Occupied:false,
    Sprite:Image,
    Type:"",
    X:0,
    Y:0
};

var Chunk={
    matrix:Block[32][24],
    background:Image,
    display:function(xindex, yindex){
        ctx.drawImage(Background,0,0);
        x=xindex;
        y=yindex;
        for(y=0; y<24; Y++){
            for(x=0; x<32; x++){
            ctx.drawImage(matrix[X][Y].sprite,X*32,Y*32);
            };
        };
    },
    loadNew:function(){
        for(Y=0; Y<24; Y++){
            for(X=0; X<32; X++){
            block=new Block;
            block.Sprite.src="test.png";
            this.matrix[X][Y]=block;
            };
        };
    }
};

var World={
    matrix:Chunk[5][5],
    indexX:0,
    indexY:0
};
```

I'm still new to js and trying to teach myself so there's probably tons of errors and stuff. But can anyone see how it doesn't want to draw on the canvas?

Comment: first of all change the order of js declaration in your page, then please prepare a jsfiddle

Comment: what should be the order, and whats a jsfiddle?

Comment: look at the javascript console of your browser. There must be some errors : file naming, file order, syntax issue (like Block[32][24]), and like. Fix this issue, then edit your post. I did a bit of code cleaning while drinking my coffee, i bet you'll be interested : http://jsfiddle.net/4QLP3/  cheers.

Comment: That jsfiddle thing sounds great and just want I need except for loading the sprites from a file. Thing is I copied it down and put it in my files and for some reason it doesn't display anything even though it does on jsfiddle. Is the naming convention essential for syntax? I left it pretty much how you wrote it even with the dummy canvas just with different names.

Comment: OK I see what the problem was lol I had the main.js implemented before the world_loader.js so it had nothing to load. you guys probably said that already but I didn't know what you meant. If I could vote up your comment GameAlchemist I would :P

Answer (score 1):

There is some problem with your script(sintax errors, scope trouble and so on), you should start with something more simple, I suggest you to start to read this [online book](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/).
Anyway below you can see a simple script to fill and display a little grid of images on a canvas.

```
var Map = (function () {
      var options = arguments[0] || {};
      var _grid = [];
      var _rNum = options.rowuUm || 10;
      var _cNum = options.colNum || 10;

      var _block = function (x, y) {
        this.img = document.getElementById('on');
        this.X = x;
        this.Y = y;

      };

      return {
        init: function () {
          for (var i = 0; i < _rNum; i++) {
            _grid[i] = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < _cNum; j++) {
              _grid[i][j] = new _block(i, j);
            }
          }
        },

        paint: function (canvasId) {
          var cnv = document.getElementById(canvasId);
          var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');
          var img = new Image();
          img.src = 'on.jpg';
          img.onload = function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < _rNum; i++) {
              for (var j = 0; j < _cNum; j++) {
                ctx.drawImage(img, i * 32, j * 32);

              }
            }
          };
        },
      }
    })();

    Map.init();
    Map.paint('canvas');
```